# Parse ASIN's and add Hyperlink

Tags: excel, google-sheets-query

Say I get a string like this `B01AVAF3AK-40 / B01AVAF5Q2-36`. I would like to copy over any ASIN's into new cells on parallel columns.

I have been using a combination of `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(B[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).*(B[a-zA-Z0-9]{9})")` and `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://www.amazon.com/dp/product/",C2),C2)`.

The problem with this approach is: 1) I can only get two ASIN's from one string. 2) I don't have a single formula that does both regex matching and adds a hyperlink. How would I solve this in Google Sheets?

Additionally how would this be done using Excel?

[My spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KW0CjLB0gaafG69d99le9HuaO31m4Oh9EnNSHKY0x4s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I won't always have the same amount of ASIN's in the input string. Anywhere between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly with Google Sheets (added solution to spreadsheet):

=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK("https://www.amazon.com/dp/product/" & REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2, "/"), "(B[a-zA-Z0-9]{9})"), REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2, "/"), "(B[a-zA-Z0-9]{9})")))

Comment: in google sheets. problem is it will only split with a "/".